# Convert varchar dd-mmm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy then order by not working?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a situation

1. I need to convert a `varchar` value from `dd-mmm-yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy`
2. order by above converted date

Using

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([Date] AS DATETIME), 103) as ModifiedDate
```

I got the required format but, when I do order by `ModifiedDate`

order by result set showing 2013, 2014, 2015 years mixed match. I think its doing order by date. Where I am doing wrong? Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: You are confusing formatting a value for display and ordering a result set. As Heinzi explains, you want to `order by` the date, e.g. `cast([Date] as Date)` to exclude the time-of-day. Formatting a value for display should, as a rule, be left for the application code, not performed by the database. (Aside: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `ModifiedDate` is a varchar, its ordering is lexical (`01/01/1900` < `01/01/1901` < `02/01/1900`).

The solution is not to use a varchar for sorting. Convert your varchar-date to a real date (i.e., only `CAST([Date] AS DATETIME)` without the outer `CONVERT`) and sort by this expression.

Comment: @ Heinzi, Thanks for the reply. but result set must be dd/mm/yyyy. its client requirement. any advise?

Comment: The result set can be in that format but for sorting purposes, you must sort by date.  AKA, do the conversion like normal in the `SELECT` but change your `ORDER BY`

Comment: @KK1960: Keep the `SELECT` clause as it is, but use the modified expression in the `ORDER BY` clause. Even better (if possible): SELECT only the real date and do the formatting in your user interface layer.

Answer (score -1):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cast ([Date] AS DATETIME),103) as ModifiedDate
from <table name> order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cast ([Date] AS DATETIME),103)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. thats what I did but the problem is in sorting. Thanks

Comment: I did @@Heinzi answer, got itThanks